# Display a related record on a single PowerApps screen

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a PowerApps screen with two forms side-by-side. Form A displays an item from List A in display mode, and Form B shows an item from list B in Edit mode, where the item in List B has the same RequestID value. I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to pass the parameter from Form A to Form B so that Form B loads the correct item. I've tried using Search, Filter, and Lookup, but in all cases, it throws an error in my formula. An example:

```
Filter(SharePointListA,RequestID=DataCardValue12.Text)
```

Or

```
Search(SharePointListA,DataCardValue12.Text,"RequestID")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a couple of things:

- RequestID is type number so you need to have **RequestID=Value(DataCardValue12.Text)** instead of RequestID=DataCardValue12.Text
- Filter and Search both return a table/collection and your form needs a Record - LookUp on the other hand returns a Record. So either use LookUp (with Value as above) or use First(Filter(...)).

A screenshot of the Form B properties pane or the error message you get could help understand what is happening

Comment: The solution was a re-write of the Lookup query. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!